# Reading in environmental Variable Using Viper Go

Tags: go, viper-go

I am trying to make Viper read my environment variables, but its not working. Here is my configuration:

```
# app.yaml
dsn: RESTFUL_APP_DSN
jwt_verification_key: RESTFUL_APP_JWT_VERIFICATION_KEY
jwt_signing_key: RESTFUL_APP_JWT_SIGNING_KEY
jwt_signing_method: "HS256"
```

And my `config.go` file:

```
package config

import (
    "fmt"
    "strings"

    "github.com/go-ozzo/ozzo-validation"
    "github.com/spf13/viper"
)

// Config stores the application-wide configurations
var Config appConfig

type appConfig struct {
    // the path to the error message file. Defaults to "config/errors.yaml"
    ErrorFile string `mapstructure:"error_file"`
    // the server port. Defaults to 8080
    ServerPort int `mapstructure:"server_port"`
    // the data source name (DSN) for connecting to the database. required.
    DSN string `mapstructure:"dsn"`
    // the signing method for JWT. Defaults to "HS256"
    JWTSigningMethod string `mapstructure:"jwt_signing_method"`
    // JWT signing key. required.
    JWTSigningKey string `mapstructure:"jwt_signing_key"`
    // JWT verification key. required.
    JWTVerificationKey string `mapstructure:"jwt_verification_key"`
}

func (config appConfig) Validate() error {
    return validation.ValidateStruct(&config,
        validation.Field(&config.DSN, validation.Required),
        validation.Field(&config.JWTSigningKey, validation.Required),
        validation.Field(&config.JWTVerificationKey, validation.Required),
    )
}

func LoadConfig(configpaths ...string) error {
    v := viper.New()
    v.SetConfigName("app")
    v.SetConfigType("yaml")
    v.SetEnvPrefix("restful")
    v.AutomaticEnv()
    v.SetDefault("error_file", "config/errors.yaml")
    v.SetDefault("server_port", 1530)
    v.SetDefault("jwt_signing_method", "HS256")
    v.SetEnvKeyReplacer(strings.NewReplacer(".", "_"))

    for _, path := range configpaths {
        v.AddConfigPath(path)
    }

    if err := v.ReadInConfig(); err != nil {
        return fmt.Errorf("Failed to read the configuration file: %s", err)
    }

    if err := v.Unmarshal(&Config); err != nil {
        return err
    }

    // Checking with this line. This is what I get:
    // RESTFUL_JWT_SIGNING_KEY
    fmt.Println("Sign Key: ", v.GetString("jwt_signing_key"))

    return Config.Validate()
}
```

This line `fmt.Println("Sign Key: ", v.GetString("jwt_signing_key"))` gives me just the key passed in the yaml file `RESTFUL_JWT_SIGNING_KEY`. I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

According to doc:

> AutomaticEnv is a powerful helper especially when combined with
>   SetEnvPrefix. When called, Viper will check for an environment
>   variable any time a viper.Get request is made. It will apply the
>   following rules. It will check for a environment variable with a name
>   matching the key uppercased and prefixed with the EnvPrefix if set.

So, why isn't it reading the environment variables?

Using `JSON`

```
{
  "dsn": "RESTFUL_APP_DSN",
  "jwt_verification_key": "RESTFUL_APP_JWT_VERIFICATION_KEY",
  "jwt_signing_key": "RESTFUL_APP_JWT_SIGNING_KEY",
  "jwt_signing_method": "HS256"
}
```

And my parser looks like thus:

```
// LoadConfigEnv loads configuration from the given list of paths and populates it into the Config variable.
// Environment variables with the prefix "RESTFUL_" in their names are also read automatically.
func LoadConfigEnv(environment string, configpaths ...string) error {
  v := viper.New()
  v.SetConfigName(environment)
  v.SetConfigType("json")
  v.SetEnvPrefix("restful")
  v.AutomaticEnv()
  v.SetDefault("jwt_signing_method", "HS256")
  v.SetDefault("error_file", "config/errors.yaml")
  v.SetDefault("server_port", 1530)
  v.SetEnvKeyReplacer(strings.NewReplacer(".", "_"))

  for _, path := range configpaths {
    v.AddConfigPath(path)
  }

  if err := v.ReadInConfig(); err != nil {
    return fmt.Errorf("Failed to read the configuration file: %s", err)
  }

  if err := v.Unmarshal(&Config); err != nil {
    return err
  }

  return Config.Validate()
}
```

In the `Validate` function, I decided to check the `Config` struct, and this is what I got:

`Config:  {config/errors.yaml 1530 RESTFUL_APP_DSN HS256 RESTFUL_APP_JWT_SIGNING_KEY RESTFUL_APP_JWT_VERIFICATION_KEY}`

Comment: Cannot reproduce: https://play.golang.org/p/YvK__C7zx13 `$ RESTFUL_JWT_SIGNING_KEY=from-env go run main.go` outputs "Sign Key:  from-env".

Comment: Add `fmt.Printf("Getenv: %q\n", os.Getenv("RESTFUL_JWT_SIGNING_KEY"))` to your program and let us know what that prints.

Comment: @Peter When I do that, it gets the Environment Variable's value `Getenv: "QfCAH04Cob7b71QCqy738vw5XGSnFZ9d"`

Comment: How do you run it? Can you make sure you are using latest version of viper?

Comment: @TarunLalwani Yes. I am. Check above, I decided to change it to `JSON` file, and still the same thing.

Comment: Which OS are you using?

Comment: @TarunLalwani I am using an `Apple MacOS`. Apparently, I have found the solution to my problem. This is actually an example of a vallue in my actual `app.yaml` file `RESTFUL_APP_DSN` a DSN value is like this: `dsn: RESTFUL_APP_DSN` so, I decided to to go through `Viper` codebase, and the decided to try `app_dsn: RESTFUL_APP_DSN` and Voila, it works fine. Which means, the **Key** must be the suffix of the prefix provided while setting up `Viper`

Comment: That's a good find. You should post the details as an answer

Comment: Done @TarunLalwani thanks.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The code in my question didn't actually show what I was trying to solve. After understanding what was wrong, I believe, the code here would have ran locally in my **Development Environment.**

According to [Viper documentation](https://github.com/spf13/viper#working-with-environment-variables):

> AutomaticEnv is a powerful helper especially when combined with SetEnvPrefix. When called, Viper will check for an environment variable any time a viper.Get request is made. It will apply the following rules. It will check for an environment variable with a name matching the key uppercased and prefixed with the EnvPrefix if set.

This line here says it all:

**It will check for a environment variable with a name matching the key uppercased and prefixed with the EnvPrefix if set**

The prefix set with `v.SetEnvPrefix("restful")` would be expecting a `.yaml` with key value of:

Example app.yaml:

```
dsn: RESTFUL_DSN
```

Notice the DSN being the **Lowercased Key** and it being used as a `Suffix` of `RESTFUL_DSN`

In my situation, I was doing this instead:

Example app.yaml:

```
dsn: RESTFUL_APP_DSN
```

So, it was checking for `RESTFUL_DSN` in my environment instead of `RESTFUL_APP_DSN`